# Make: command could not be found

Tags: c++, cygwin

I am using Cygwin to compile some C++ files.
there is an file named Makefile. Now when I use this command in Cygwin,

```
make -f Makefile
```

the following error is displaying.

```
-bash: make: command not found
```

Could someone tell me what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to install the make package. I'm not sure about the package name but try using "sudo apt-get install make" and press tab key to see if have some package. I had this problem one time and in someway the make command wasn't installed in my machine, I installed the package and it worked!

I hope it help!